# equals() gives me null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, package

This is my equal method:

```
public boolean equals(Car other)
{
if (other == null)
{
    return false;
}

if (this.genre.equals(other.genre))
{

    if (this.price == other.price && this.height == other.height && this.name == other.name && this.door = other.door)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
else
{
    return false;
}

}
```

For some reason, this line gives me a null pointer exception: this.genre.equals(other.genre)

genre is a variable from another package;

All variables were declared in the class Car. The program compiles fine.

This is the constructor of Car:

```
    public Car(double price, float height, String genre, String name, int door)
{
    super(price, height, genre);
            this.name = name;
            this.door = door;

}
```

Why am I getting a null pointer exception?

Comment: Well what about if `genre` is null...? Also note that your inner `if` block could be completely collapsed to `return this.price == other.price` etc, rather than an `if` with `return true`, `return false` branches.

Comment: By the way: `name` is a String you should compare it with `equals(..)` not `this.name == other.name`

Comment: genre is null indeed, but how do i change that?

Comment: You should be implementing `equals(Object o)` and doing an `instanceof` check.  Writing a method `equals(Car other)` will have no effect on e.g. all the collections that use `equals`.

Comment: @prog: of course, genre is null. But you did neither show the code of `Car`'s superclass nor the code of the caller...

Comment: can't i call super in the constructor for genre???

Comment: If it won't be possible to call super, the compiler would have told you. Point is that genre is null, and there are exactly two possible causes: 1) caller sent a null object to Car constructor, 2) Cars' superclass is buggy... (given that genre is immutable). As I said - show the code.

Comment: ok it works after i made a constructor without genre and modified my constructor in the car class. my car class couldn't access the variable in the package, because it wasn't in the same package!

Answer (score 2):

Because `this.genre` is null?

```
if (this.genre != null && this.genre.equals(other.genre))
```

Comment: This will give you wierd result. You are negating a `string`?

Comment: It should say `this.genre != null`

Comment: genre is not null, but ill try to add that condition

Answer (score 0):

Start using a library that correctly handles nulls when performing string comparisons.

Start using apache commons lang.  Here is the [StringUtils JavaDoc page](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are equaling with `null` String `genre` in Car Object which cause `NullPointerExcaption`.

```
if (this.genre!=null && this.genre.equals(other.genre)){...}
```

One more thing -

```
...
if(...this.door = other.door){
           ^^^^
```

It should be `==`.